# Java EventHandler on Taskbar Icon

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to listen for a mouse click on the icon shown in the taskbar (not System Tray)? My problem is that I am using an undecorated window for my GUI, and that causes me to lose the ability to minimize the application by clicking on the taskbar icon. Currently I minimize the application via a button I have added to the scene. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have a feeling [this library could be helpful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692(v=vs.85).aspx). However I don't know how to use it within Java.